# How to get the closest object in the navMesh and making the agent move towards it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

At the moment I have a semi-dynamic layout where my agent follows the randomized waypoints and after he reaches one, he deletes said waypoint.
However, I want him to scan the closest waypoint to the object. Taking into account vector3.distance goes over obstacles, what are the other solutions.

```
    public NavMeshAgent agent;
    public GameObject[] waypoints // Waypoints
    public Transform[] locations // Waypoint location
    for (int x = 0; x < waypoints.Length; x++) // Sets random position
    {
        if (x < 5) 
        {
            waypoints[x].transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-33.0f, 30.0f), 3.575465f, Random.Range(30.0f, -35.0f));
        }

        for (int z = 0; z < waypoints.Length; z++)
        {
            if (z < 5 && waypoints[z] != null)
            {
                agent.SetDestination(locations[z].position);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the closes point in the the NavMesh  with [`NavMesh.SamplePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMesh.SamplePosition.html) or [`NavMeshAgent.SamplePathPosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/ScriptReference/NavMeshAgent.SamplePathPosition.html). The second argument `maxDistance` is used to determine the max distance to search the object.

This returns [`NavMeshHit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshHit.html). You can access the position with [`NavMeshHit.position`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshHit-position.html) and pass it to `NavMeshAgent.SetDestination` to move there.

Something like this:

```
private NavMeshAgent agent;
private int waterMask;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    waterMask = 1 << NavMesh.GetAreaFromName("Water");
}

void Update()
{
    NavMeshHit hit;

    // Check all areas one length unit ahead.
    if (!agent.SamplePathPosition(NavMesh.AllAreas, 1.0F, out hit))
    {
        if ((hit.mask & waterMask) != 0)
        {
            // Water detected along the path...

            //Move to it
            agent.SetDestination(hit.position);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't that just check a random position and move in a random direction?

Comment: Also this is probably asking for too much, but how would i adapt this into my code?